# Getting error Operation timed out after 100096 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received

Tags: php, laravel-4, youtube-api

I am trying to use youtube api to upload video from my website to other in laravel for which i am using fbf/youtube package of laravel.
But i am getting the error

> Operation timed out after 100096 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes
>   received

What could be the problem.